# Unable to store value in array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

What i'm willing to do is i wanna convert all the values of the array to their respective ASCII values and then **store them in another array**. My code is able to convert the character values into ASCII but it fails in storing them in another array. Please help me out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char ass[10];
    char name[]= "Chaitanya";
    int size=sizeof(name);
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        int p=name[i];
        cout<<p<<"\n";
        for(int j=0; j<size; j++){
            ass[j]=p;
            }
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

When I try to run this program I get the following error message:

```
warning: variable ‘ass’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
```

Thank You!
I got the previous one. But what if i wanna print all those elements stored in ass once again. I'm using the following code and it does nothing. I'm not getting any error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char ass[10];
    char name[]= "Chaitanya";
    int size=sizeof(name);
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        int p=name[i];
        cout<<p<<"\n";
        for(int j=0; j<size; j++){
            ass[j]=p;
            }
        }
    for(int q=0; q<size; q++){
        cout<<ass[q];
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: "convert the character values into ASCII" - This doesn't mean anything. The character values are already numeric codes that are typically interpreted as a superset of ASCII. Everything else is a matter of presentation, i.e. whether to show that numeric code by looking up a glyph in a table (treat it as a character) or by converting it to the string representation of the number (treat it as an integer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your warning is just telling you that you aren't using the variable `ass`. It's not an error, but you *do* have a problem in your code:

```
int size = sizeof(name);

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    int p = name[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        ass[j] = p;
    }
}
```

The second for loop will simply overwrite each character in `ass` with the single character `p`. A nested for loop isn't needed, just assign the character from the main loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    int p = name[i];
    ass[i] = p;
}
```

Moreover, this can be facilitated through the Standard Library functions. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string ass;
    std::string name = "Chaitanya";

    for (auto a : name)
    {
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(a);
    }

    ass = name;
    std::cout << ass; // "Chaitanya"
```

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion. I think overwriting is a good idea instead of running the nested loop. Thumbs up to you

Answer (score 2):

Your warning is not a failure. It's just pointing out that once you store it, you never use it!

Comment: More precisely you don't cout << ... the values in 'ass'.

Comment: But this does not print the value stored in ass[0]. I want to print all the elements stored in ass once again but it's not working.

Comment: The code you've posted has no attempt to print them out again. Put the whole code in and then we'll have a look!

Answer (score 1):

The warning is correct, you only set the values of `ass` you do not use the values set afterwards. If you added let's say a `cout` after the loop the warning would go away:

```
std::cout << ass[0] << std::endl ;
```

I also, don't think you need the second inner loop, if you want to print out each element of `ass` you could add it that after you set it. So the fix and additions print out could look like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    int p=name[i];
    cout<<p<<"\n";

    ass[i]=p;
    std::cout << ass[i] << std::endl ;        
}
```

Comment: But this does not print the value stored in ass[0]. I want to print all the elements stored in ass once again but it's not working.

Comment: @ChaitanyaChoudhary added some more details

Answer (score 1):

> warning: variable ‘ass’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]

This warning just say that you have set the variable `ass` but you never use it. It is not an error at all.

As an example, try to output a value for this array and **the warning will disappear**:

```
std::cout << ass[0] << std::endl;
```

There is a little part on this warning here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html.